# How to give a Timer thread a name?

Tags: python, timer, python-multithreading

I use a recurring python timer thread and would like to give it a name.  Currently, python gives every new thread the name `Thread-<number>` and increments the number on every new timer start.  I would like the name to remain the same. The basic `Thread` class supports being named, `Timer`s, however, do not:

```
class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *,
                       daemon=None)
```

**Note** the `name=None` attribute, which does not exist in `Timer`.

```
class threading.Timer(interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None)
```

Any ideas on how I can give a `Timer` a name?  I guess I could derive my own `Timer` class and add `name`, but I don't think the python interpreter would pick it up as the thread's name...

Comment: Class `threading._Timer` is derived from `Thread`. If you look at the [Lib/threading.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/threading.py#l1035) source code you'll see how easy it would be to define your own subclass that had a `name` attribute just like its baseclass. i.e. call `Thread.__init__(self, name=xxx)` in the sublcass's `__init__()` method.

Comment: Yes, thanks, makes sense. Will give it a try.

Comment: Again, from the source code in [Lib/threading.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/threading.py#l629), in the `Thread` class itself `name` is a property which internally accesses the private attribute `self.__name` — so you can manipulate its value though the property's `@name.setter` method (or even do so directly, although that breaks encapsulation) after a `Timer` object is instantiated or from within your own subclass.

Comment: No need to overload the _Timer class: I just assign the desired designator to the Timer using its parent property 'name'

Timer.name = my_name

Works, and in the parent class documentation it even states to use it - break encapsulation, but in this case that seems ok.

name
A string used for identification purposes only. It has no semantics. Multiple threads may be given the same name. The initial name is set by the constructor.

Comment: You misunderstood what I meant. Using the (inherited) `name` property is fine — it was accessing the private `__name` attribute that would break encapsulation. Anyway, glad to hear your problem's solved.

Comment: Ah, yes, many thanks for the clarification re __name and name properties.

Answer (score 6):

`Timers` are a `Thread` subclass, which have names, so you can assign a custom name to one *after* it's created by just assigning a value to its `name` attribute—so it doesn't matter that the `Timer` constructor doesn't accept an argument allowing this.

If you do this a lot, you could write a relatively trivial utility function that automated doing this for you (or derive your own `NamedTimer(Timer)` subclass, which would be about the same number of lines of code):

```
try:
    from threading import Timer
except ImportError:
    from threading import _Timer as Timer  # Python <3.3

def named_timer(name, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
    """Factory function to create named Timer objects.

      Named timers call a function after a specified number of seconds:

          t = named_timer('Name', 30.0, function)
          t.start()
          t.cancel()  # stop the timer's action if it's still waiting
    """
    timer = Timer(interval, function, *args, **kwargs)
    timer.name = name
    return timer

if __name__ == '__main__':

    def func():
        print('func() called')

    timer = named_timer('Fidgit', 3, func)
    print('timer.name: {!r}'.format(timer.name))  # -> timer.name: 'Fidgit'
    timer.run()  # Causes "func() called" to be printed after a few seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked for the same information and landed here. I found that one way of doing this is:

```
timer = Timer(interval, function)
timer.setName('AnyTimerName')
```

Comment: Use of the `setName()` method is deprecated per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.setName). Since nowdays `name` is a `Timer` property, it can and should be accessed directly: i.e. `timer.name = 'AnyTimerName'`